# Is there a neat way to invert an embedded pattern-match in a regular expression in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

All, I have the following code:

```
Readonly my $CTRL_CHARS => qr{[|!?*]}xsm;

my ($dbix_object, $alias, $cardinality) = ($object =~ qr{
        ^                 # Start of the line
        ([^|*?!]*)        # Anything that isn't a relationship control character
                          #   i.e.    | (indicating an alias)
                          #           * (indicating many_to_many)
                          #           ? (indicating might_have)
                          #           ! (indicating has_one)
        \|?               # Possible |, indicating an alias follows
        ([^|!?*]*?)       # Possible alias (excludes all the control characters above)
        ([|!?*]?)$        # Possible control character
       }oxsm);
```

I'd like to replace the punctuation vomit within the regex with the pattern defined as `$CTRL_CHARS`. However, when I put something like: `[^$CTRL_CHARS]`, Perl complains, because this is expanded out as `[^(?msx-i:[|!?*])]`. Understandably, Perl pitches a fit at the invalid character range `x-i`.

One solution would be to use the following:

```
Readonly my $CTRL_CHARS     => qr{[|!?*]}xsm;
Readonly my $NON_CTRL_CHARS => qr{[^|!?*]}xsm;
```

There's repetition there, which I don't like... but they're close together, so maybe that's not such a bad thing.

What I'd like to know is if there's a simple way to invert the meaning of `$CTRL_CHARS`, either for the definition of `$NON_CTRL_CHARS` or for direct use within the regex.

Another approach would be to define a character class, but I don't know how to do that and can't find any simple one liners to do it (would have to be a simple one liner, I think, to justify it)

Comment: `=~ qr{}` is a bit weird. `=~ m{}` is the same, but less confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `$CTRL_CHARS` is guaranteed to be a char class, then you can use

```
(?! $CTRL_CHARS . )
```

But why not just define

```
Readonly my $CTRL_CHARS => '|!?*';

[$CTRL_CHARS]
[^$CTRL_CHARS]
```

Comment: Your second options suffers from the same problem as mine; it just expands out to: `[^(?msx-i:|!?*)]`

Comment: @Dancrumb, I just remembered you can create custom character properties, and that they are negatable. They are [described](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#User-Defined-Character-Properties) in perlunicode.